# Finding a transformation that squares the components of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, transformation

I am looking for a transformation (of any type, as long as it can be written mathematically and not semantically) which takes a vector of infinite dimensions to another vector that has components which are squares are the first. That is to say,

$T(x_1,x_2,x_3...) = (x_1^2,x_2^2,x_3^2...)$

for such a transformation T.

My very first knee-jerk thought was that I could take the dot product of my vector with itself, or else multiply the transpose of my vector with itself, because these both have the property of multiplying each component of the vector itself, but then both do the annoying thing and then sum all of these together.

My next thought was to construct an infinite diagonal matrix where each entry was equal to the corresponding component in the vector, but I couldn't find an easy way to construct this matrix algebraically for the general vector.

Any speculation about whether this question is possible or even makes sense is more than welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically and not semantically"? I think you are asking whether you can write $T$ using some standard algebraic operations, but to do that you need to decide what algebraic structure you are imposing on $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}$. If you view it as a product of rings, then $T(\mathbf{x})$ is $\mathbf{x}^2$, but that is probably harder to understand and has more mental prerequisites than the definition that you give in your question and don't seem to like.

Comment: What you wrote is "mathematical". Maybe you meant "just using vector space stuff, like matrix multiplication"?

Comment: @RobArthan tragically, I don't know enough about rings as I'd like, so the rest of this comment might not make sense in context, but I need something I can work with that can easily allow me to add this new vector to itself, or to a vector with all values equal to some constant

Comment: @JonathanZ, yes exactly

Comment: @JonathanZ: thanks for a helpful intervention.

Comment: I don't believe you can define this notation just using vector space stuff (although we'd need to make a lot more notational things precise to begin a proof of that belief). But the definition as you give it is absolutely fine: if you are working with mathematical objects like $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}$ that are handed to you with an explicit representation of the elements (in this case as sequences of reals), then it is fine to define functions using the details of those internal representations. It is nice if you can get by with standard algebraic operations, but not essential.

Comment: @RobArthan - Heh, I knew that writing "vector space stuff" was kicking a can down the road, and that we'd still need to make _that_ more precise, but I guess it was a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$$\boldsymbol{y}= {\rm diag}( \boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{x}^\intercal )$$

Which takes the diagonal elements matrix formed from the outer product of $\boldsymbol{x}$ with itself.

Comment: But that's much harder to understand than the component-wise definition in the question that the OP doesn't seem to like. And it raises concerns because multiplication of matrices of infinite dimension doesn't make sense in general.